# Expo app, intent filter for youtube not working

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, expo

I'm creating an app that has to be appear after sharing from youtube, but my intent filters are not working

I'm using dev builds with `npx expo run:android --variant release`

```js
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";

export default function App() {
  const url = Linking.useURL()

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>URL: {url}</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

this is my generated (by my app.json) android manifest

```xml
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.ticua.intents"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter data-generated="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="youtube.com" android:pathPrefix="/watch"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter data-generated="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="youtube.com" android:pathPrefix="/watch"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I tried sharing with youtube and the app wasn't listed as an option to share, but using `npx uri-scheme open` worked but only with com.ticua.intents

It once worked but in an older version of Android (Android 9 I think) but in Android 14 it isn't
EDIT: ACTION_VIEW does work but ACTION_SEND doesn't, I can confirm this

using `am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https://youtube.com/watch -n com.ticua.intents` does show the URL later, but ACTION_SEND doesn't show it